# Queue is failing

Tags: queue

I have an issue with queue running... It always fails.

[image]

The same with image transforms and so on...

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, the issue was with one of the plugins that I use.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how you arrived at this conclusion? Examples of things that would help the community: the plugin you identified, your queue setup, memory limits, troubleshooting steps, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Try to increase the memory size for PHP. You seem to allow 32MB whereas Craft CMS recommends at least 256MB. I am not too familiar with cPanel, but I think you can change that setting under Software > Select PHP Version > Options. There should be a setting `memory_limit`which should be 256M or better 512M.

Comment: Memory limit is 512MB. Now I'm getting this problem only with images, the rest works well. Maybe it's worth mentioning that recently I changed PHP version.... Cannot find the solution for this for days already :(

Comment: Can you log in to the commandline (ssh) of your server and run a basic craft command to see if that basically works ? like `php craft queue/run -v`

What about `max_execution_time`?

Is there anything notable about the error in `storage/logs/phperrors.log`?

Comment: `[telefonai@srv public_html]$ php craft queue/run -v
2022-09-20 11:15:27 [pid: 4787] - Worker is started
2022-09-20 11:15:27 [pid: 4787] - Worker is stopped (0:00:00)
[telefonai@srv public_html]$` . In phperrrors.log I have a lot of `"[20-Sep-2022 10:52:45 Europe/Vilnius] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted"` for different plugins..